# declaring empty types in go

Tags: go

For a given type `Data` , I would like to define a set of filters, each processing `Data` in a certain way. Some filters only need the data to be processed, other may need additional parameters.

```
type Data struct {
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to define a list of filters, and apply them sequentially to an instance of `Data`. To acheive this, I defined a `Filter` interface :

```
type Filter interface {
    Apply (d *Data) error
}
```

To define a filter, all I have to do is create a new type and define the Apply method for it.

Now, let's say I have a filter that does not need any additional information. **Is it good practice to define it as an empty `struct` ?**

```
type MySimpleFilter struct {}

func (f *MySimpleFilter) Apply (d *Data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to adopt a slightly more functional approach and have the Apply method of Filter return a new instance of Data, instead of having to mutate the Data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd argue this is good practice if you have no use for a Field, especially compared to using another type (i.e. `type MySimpleFilter int`) because an empty struct uses no space:

https://codereview.appspot.com/4634124

and it can still fulfill interface contracts (hence can be more useful than a functional approach in some cases).

This can also be a good idiom when using a map that you have no use for the value (i.e. `map[string]struct{}`). See this discussion for details:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/lb4xLHq7wug

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that doesn't have a clear answer since it's a matter of taste. I'd say it is good practice because it makes MySimpleFilter symmetrical to the other filters, which makes it easier to understand the code.